# Left and right arrow icons centered in a div

Tags: html

I want to place two icons for navigation backward and forward in a footer at the bottom of the page with a space of 10px between them.

The two icons must be at the same vertical level and together centered horizontally.
How can I do that?

```
<div id="footer"> 
  <i id="left" class="fa fa-caret-left fa-5x"></i>
  <i id="right" class="fa fa-caret-right fa-5x"></i>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a container for them that is centered horizontally and put them in there. So long as the two icons together aren't bigger than the screen they will be shown side by side. To create a space of 10px between them you can add a margin to the right of the first element like this:

```
<!-- website -->
<div style="text-align: center">
    <span style="margin-right: 10px">ICON</span><span>ICON</span>
</div>
<!-- website -->
```

Replace the span tags with the icons.

EDIT: I see you edited your question, with the code provided it should be sufficient to add "text-align: center" to the css for footer and "margin-right: 10px" to the css for left

Answer (score 0):

If you use `display:table;` for the parent element and `display:table-cell;` for the child elements, you are able to align them horizontally centered.

https://jsfiddle.net/3do9gvx3/1/

```css
#footer{
  display:table;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
#footer i{
  padding: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#left{
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer"> 
  <i id="left" class="fa fa-caret-left fa-5x">Test</i>
  <i id="right" class="fa fa-caret-right fa-5x">Test</i>    
</div>
```